# Driver LED PT4115

Tags: led

I'm a beginner and I came across this drive, I intend to use it to control the light of some LEDs using PWM and I also want to make a voltage reduction in a microcontroller (ESP-32) using it too and I wanted to understand a little more about this circuit, because I have some doubts.

For example, I would like to have a:

- Input: 24 V
- Output: 12 V

Constantly, without using PWM, and after it add an AMS1117-3.3 to regulate the voltage that goes to the ESP ESP-32, as shown in the image below

But I can't understand where it will be responsible for regulating the output voltage, because from what I see (Vin) goes straight to R 0.3 Ω and goes to output +, would the resistor be the item that will regulate the output voltage?

I did some tests with some resistors here at home, but the same input voltage, it was on the output, so I would like to know in detail how this drive works

**PT4115 datasheet:**

[image]

**My circuit, I already saw that there are some things wrong, but this is more or less the idea I want to do:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome! There are no LEDs in your schematic. Please add them. the LED driver will not regulate output voltage, only current. You can't use the output of the LED driver to power your MCU without significant headache. There are plenty of switching regulators which will take your 24 V input to 3.3 V for your ESP-32.

Comment: Wow thank you could you tell me some? so i might be searching,
thank you again

Comment: You might find my old test on PT4115 helpful: How can Rpi Python PWM GPIO pins control and dim LED strips of 1W 350mA? - RpiSE, Asked 1 year, 10 months ago, Viewed 892 times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/122187/how-can-rpi-python-pwm-gpio-pins-control-and-dim-led-strips-of-1w-350ma

Comment: @Leonardo 1. go to a reputable electronics component seller – digikey, mouser, farnell, rs components… 2. click through to the power control ICs, switch-mode converters 3. enter your requirements 4. Success.